# Complex destructuring of array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, axios, es6-promise, destructuring

Consider I have the following code which makes a GET request;

```
const [
    {data: a},
    {data: b},
    {data: c},
    {data: d}
] = await Promise.all([
    axios.get('https://api.somesite.org/a.json'),
    axios.get('https://api.somesite.org/b.json'),
    axios.get('https://api.somesite.org/c.json'),
    axios.get('https://api.somesite.org/d.json')
]);
```

Now, since it is via Axios, I assume response would always be full response and for Promise.all, we'll get an array of response objects looking something like below;

```
[{
data: {
    "a1": "1",
    "a11": "11"
},
headers: {},
status: 200
}, {
data: {
    "b2": "2",
    "b22": "22"
},
headers: {},
status: 200
}, {
data: {
    "c3": "3",
    "c33": "33"
},
headers: {},
status: 200
}, {
data: {
    "d4": "4",
    "d44": "44"
},
headers: {},
status: 200
}
]
```

Now, here is how I believe the code is evaluated (and I just need confirmation on the below sequence of steps):

First the array destructuring syntax is executed, which means for the first item in the array, it gets assigned. So, in effect we should get 1st array element assigned as below;

```
{data: a} = {
data: {
    "a1": "1",
    "a11": "11"
},
headers: {},
status: 200
}
```

Same thing happens for the other 3 array elements

The next step would be an object destructuring syntax execution. So, from the right hand side object, it would pull "data" property value and assign it to the alias "a"

So, in effect, variable "a" should get the object assigned as below;

```
{
    "a1": "1",
    "a11": "11"
}
```

Is my understanding of the above sequence of code execution correct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the right-hand side of the assignment will be evaluated first, so you'd get to the destructuring only *after* the promise is resolved.

Comment: Yes, that part would be clear to me...I mainly needed confirmation on the execution post the promise resolving (i.e. once we get promise of array of response)

Comment: In that case, I'm pretty sure it's not full array destructuring -> full object destructuring, but rather: resolve first element of array -> object destructure it -> resolve second element of array -> etc. I'm not really sure why that order would matter, though.

Comment: I do not want to understand at that level...But at a more broader level...like would the array destructuring first happen, followed by object destructuring ?

Comment: I'm not completely convinced and I really don't want to dig around through the specs (they are not the easiest to read...) but I think you'll resolve element by element. So, first get the first element of the array, then extract the `data` property, then assign it to `a`. Repeat for `b`, `c`, and `d`. I do not believe you first resolve all of the array, then all of the object destructuring. Still, I do not believe the order would really make a difference in practice - you'd get the same result either way.

Comment: Created a typescript playground that targets ES3. See how it handles destructuring in an old-school way [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBA2gbxgEwIZVQLhqmBfAGhiTQ2wCN8iT0sZh8BdGAXhgB5UwBPAPkQCwAKFJ0EwmJJgAiVAEZp2aQoISpsuQqWbpwwsIAWAU1TIjAJwjYE+odHQBXKzABMABjd6C4kbWtrJaXItGRUAmWCQ5QUvQxMzS2tbeygnbHdPIUIfUX8hKRlgKLD89SLimKzVIWNTC2cbapS01w8vHL9icOlkYulqgp6dbUrbWoSG5IxU5wy9RmFhUEgQABsjADpVkABzAApUInIiYABKRaFgVdQICBQHAFsH7h8CvSA)

Comment: @Eldar you could have just used ES5. ES3 doesn't really have any special changes needed. EDIT: also, I think Babel would be better showcase than TS.

Comment: @VLAZ I thought so. And I did, The result is the very same. First, assign the array and map the values.

Comment: Thanks a lot....So...the TS playground transpilation seems to be very close to the steps I have broken into...Isn't it ?

Comment: I was under the impression that your steps were "resolve entire array" first, followed by "destructure each object in that array".

Answer (score 0):

> Is my understanding of the above sequence of code execution correct?

Yes. Ultimately, the `await`, promises and axios stuff is irrelevant for this - at the end, you've just got a destructuring assignment with an array value.

Array destructuring works by iterating the value, assigning element by element into the respective target pattern.

Comment: Thanks...so the array is destructured and then we also have the object destructuring...Would that be correct?

Comment: Yes. Each iterated value is assigned to the respective target element, which in your case is an object destructuring pattern.